# CSS make a card fade in and then fade out on page load

Tags: html, css, fadeout

I am trying to get this card to fade in and then fade out as soon as the page loads:

```
<style>
.container {

    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
    animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeinout {
  0%,100% { opacity: 0; }
  50% { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fadeinout {
  0%,100% { opacity: 0; }
  50% { opacity: 1; }
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    You are logged in!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The card looks just fine but doesn't have any animation.

I have also tried this:

```
<style>
.container{ 
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s; /* Safari */
}
</style>

<div onload="document.getElementById(test).style.opacity='1'">
    <div class="container" id="test">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        @if (session('status'))
                            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                {{ session('status') }}
                            </div>
                        @endif

                        You are logged in!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But neither make the container the card is in fade out. I'm pretty new to css so I'm open to suggestions. This may not be the best approach but I figured I'd try to it myself first.

Comment: Ive looked at it in action and when the document loads the card fades in and out. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You're telling me it works properly for you? Which method are you using?

Comment: If you want **really** do something when page loaded, or while loading or etc.. you need to use some js

Comment: @Pedram Yeah i agree that would be a way better approach at it than using the css animation property. Saying that some browsers might not run it correctly or might not work on all of them. It's best to use some raw javascript, jquery or something so that you can modify the page either as its loading, when its done loading, etc. I've looked into it and there are multiple browsers that don't have the animation property thus not making this approach that browser friendly.

Comment: Pedram is right you need to use the JS onload listener, and run a JS anime setinterval method.

Comment: @ColePerry I've changed it for you to be more browser friendly by using jquery library. I will go ahead and do it in pure javascript for you too just to have. If this works please upvote and accept my answer

Answer (score 1):

I ran the first snippet in jsfiddle.net and the red card seems to fade in and then out like you wanted.

https://jsfiddle.net/q2cymof9/

```
<style>
  .container {

    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
    animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes fadeinout {

    0%,
    100% {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    50% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

  @keyframes fadeinout {

    0%,
    100% {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    50% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>

        <div class="card-body">
          @if (session('status'))
          <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            {{ session('status') }}
          </div>
          @endif

          You are logged in!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What browser are you using? You can check if it will work for your web browser by going to this link https://caniuse.com/#search=animation

Here is the jquery for it to make it more browser friendly!

```
<style>
  .container {

    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
  }

</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>

        <div class="card-body">
          @if (session('status'))
          <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            {{ session('status') }}
          </div>
          @endif

          You are logged in!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$('.container').hide();
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.container').delay(1000).fadeIn();
  $('.container').delay(5000).fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: I used this code instead of mine and it still does not fade in or out in Firefox, IE, or Vivaldi

Comment: If it makes a difference this is inside a Laravel project.

Comment: Hmm im not completley sure it should work. Are you including your jquery in the main app page?

Comment: @ColePerry Do you have a discord that i can make a server and we can talk on there and i can help you?

Comment: Absolutely man thank you so much.  My name is ZoeyOneOhOne#9017. I appreciate this so much.

Comment: @ColePerry sorry for the delay i was at work. Here is the discord link to a private room. https://discord.gg/E6eNT8

Comment: Hey man it's okay I got held up yesterday too. I will try to talk to you this evening.